# How do I add a "case" to a switch statement programically in C?

Tags: c

If I have a switch statement like this one:

```c
switch(x)
{
    case 1:
        printf("Hello, world!");
    case 2:
        printf("Hello!");
}
```

How can I programically place new `case` statements inside the `switch` statements?

This is an example of what I want:

```c
switch(x)
{
    case 1:
        printf("Hello, world!");
    case 2:
        printf("Hello!");
}
AddCaseStatementToSwitchStatement("case 3: printf(\"Hi!\")");
```

Comment: You can't.  What problem are you actually trying to solve?  There's likely a better solution.

Comment: You are probably missing `break` here. Anyway, just what do you mean "programmatically"? You can't do that in C, you need a different solution (a map from number to data). Maybe pseudo code of what you want would be helpful.

Comment: @hyde Sure let me edit the question a bit...

Comment: In order to do metaprogramming you can use the preprocessor. Or you could write another program which outputs C source code.

Comment: Could you add WHY you would want to do this? Maybe give an example?

Comment: you can do this with switch as C is compiled language,but since switch support only intger in c,to achieve dynamic case match with target ,you can make an array of struct with case val and callback function,now make function exe_switch which accept target case,and loop through the array and execute matching case call back,

Comment: @ShadowMitia I am making a module for a kernel in C, which contains functions for starting processes, stopping processes, etc. The start process function returns an exit code. I made a settings command in the kernel where I can add exit codes, and their messages. I want to make a `switch` statement that can have `case` statements added to it everytime an exit code is applied from the settings command. These case statements check what error code it has, and then returns the definition of the error code that is defined when using the settings command...

Comment: You can't really modify code at run time unless you are a programming wizard.  What you can do is modify the *data* (variables) that the code operates on.  So you need to think about what that data would look like (e.g. maybe you want an array that maps integer values to behaviors).

Comment: What is the range of valid `x`?

Comment: @hyde X is supposed to be in range of 0 to 2^32, since I want the kernel to add exit codes to X whenever it needs during runtime

Comment: you need a lookup table - now that you have explained what you are actually tring to do. A table of err number to error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a lookup table

```
struct err_def {
    int code;
    char* message;
};

int main() {

    struct err_def errs[] = { 
        {1,"Hello, world!"},
        {2,"Hello"}
    };
    int sz = 2;
    int errorCode = 2;
    char* msg;
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        if (errs[i].code == errorCode) {
            msg = errs[i].message;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

this one is static but you can do the same thing with a dynamically growing table

If the table gets big you can search it more efficiently by keeping it sorted and doing a binary chop on it

Comment: I feel this answer is missing the `AddCaseStatementToSwitchStatement` part... Also a mention of performance (unsorted list for O(1) addition but O(n) lookup vs sorted listed for O(n) addition but O(logn) lookup) would be nice.